# Transferring files via ssh but without scp or sftp

Tags: ssh, fuse, file-transfer

I need to transfer files via `ssh`, but unfortunately `scp` and `sftp` are not viable, as the host I am connecting is just a "door" node that is redirecting me to a different machine available only on a private supercomputing network to which it is attached (and thus it's asking me for the password twice). For this reason, I cannot run any command on the door node.

I wonder if I can transfer files using some tool that uses the output (terminal) stream from the ssh connection.

The only alternative would be outputting the files in some handy format such as base64, copying them to clipboard and decoding them locally (and vice-versa).

I am starting to get frustrated using vim remotely. What I want to achieve is a rsync-like system in which I edit the source code of my program locally and then test it remotely, but as you can see, it is not that easy.

I might not be the only one that had this problem, so I guess that there must exists a tool that has this aim? (A solution with FUSE would be the best, but I know this may be asking too much).

Comment: https://meinit.nl/using-tar-and-ssh-to-efficiently-copy-files-preserving-permissions

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz : I cannot do that because the files are not on the "door" node but on a different machine that the door node is redirecting me to. This after prompting me with a custom program that asks me what is the destination machine. For this reason I cannot run any command on the door node.

Comment: What operating system does your source file lies on ? Another Linux/Unix machine or Windows ? Also, are these ASCII/Text files or binary files?

Comment: @MelBurslan : it's all Linux. The files are mostly `lua` code, hence not very voluminous

Comment: is key based authentication available on the intermediary and final destination boxes or does it **have to** be password authenticated ?

Comment: also I never used it hence don't know the authentication schema, but, `sshfs` might be a solution.

Comment: Is it possible to ssh to the door node and then ssh from the door node to the target machine in two separate steps? If so, I may have a solution that works for you.

Comment: @MelBurslan : good point. I think it has to be password authenticated, no possibility of setting key access. `sshfs` would not work, as it cannot get into the destination node, I suppose.

Comment: @merlin2011 : no, the door node does not offer filesystem access, nor possibility of running commands, nor a shell, nothing. Just an interactive program that uses `ncurses` to select the destination network.

Comment: `ssh user@host cat file > localfile`? -- oh wait, there's an interactive program, so that wouldn't work?

Answer (score 5):

I did not want to leave this as an answer but the comments section is gettinfg larger and you will get notification from SE to carry the conversation to a chat window.

So, hit `enter` a couple of times and type `~?` no spaces. no nothing.

you should see something like this (or exactly like this)

```
Supported escape sequences:
  ~.  - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
  ~B  - send a BREAK to the remote system
  ~C  - open a command line
  ~R  - Request rekey (SSH protocol 2 only)
  ~^Z - suspend ssh
  ~#  - list forwarded connections
  ~&  - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
  ~?  - this message
  ~~  - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

at this point type `~C` and you should see `ssh>` prompt. At this point type

```
ssh> !scp /path/to/some/file/on/your/local/machine user@remoteserver
```

since you are already authenticated, it should transfer the file over the existing connection.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much you want to automate things, `expect` is an option to relay data through the bastion host and on to internal systems by "typing" things into the SSH session as a human would, only faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
  puts stderr "Usage: $argv0 bastion internalhost localfile"
  exit 1
}

set basthost [lindex $argv 0]
set desthost [lindex $argv 1]
set fileup   [lindex $argv 2]

spawn ssh -a -e none -o ClearAllForwardings=yes -x $basthost

# TODO login foo here for bastion host, e.g. send the password
# if see that prompt

expect {
  # TODO handle timeout, eof, etc.

  # TODO I have no idea what your ncurses interface looks
  # like, though there's doubtless something that could
  # be matched and the appropriate input sent to it...
  -ex "$ " {
    send -- "ssh $desthost\r"
    # TODO handle subsequent login to the internal host here
  }
}
```

Then once you have an editor or whatever open on the destination host (via appropriate `send` statements), feed data to it via:

```
set upfd [open $fileup]
while {[gets $upfd line] >= 0} {
  send -- "$line\r"
}
```

And then use more `send` calls to save the file, exit out, etc. Also, error handling, etc.

Comment: You can also use [python expect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/), which IMO is a bit nicer of an interface.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is configuration, where you set up your host to go through the "door" or rather jumpbox. You `~/.ssh/config` will look somehow like this:

```
Host door
  Hostname door.example.com
  User username_on_door
  # ...
Host target
  Hostname tagret.example.com
  User user_on_target
  # ...
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p door
```

Then you can connect with one command directly to your target system: `ssh target`

Then you can also transfer files back and forth with single command:

```
ssh taget "tar czpf - /some/important/data" | tar xzpf - -C /new/root/directory
tar cpf - /some/important/data | ssh target "tar xpf - -C /some/directory/"
```

or even start `sshfs` on to that host:

```
sshfs target:/dir/ /mnt/target
```

Not too complicated, isn't it?

Comment: sshfs depends on an sftp server on the remote machine. But the first part using piped stdio is great and IMHO the best answer that does not need any other tools.

Comment: With recent versions of the ssh client "ProxyCommand ss -W %h:%p door" could be replace with "ProxyJump door"

Answer (score 0):

You can try `scp2` from here https://github.com/alingse/scp2

It's a stupid and slow way.

```
scp2 -f ./scp2/core.py -u user@IP:~/core.py
```

here it run two steps

```
1. file --> base64 --> chunk --> ssh.execute(echo "[chunk body]" >> /tmpfile)
2. ssh.execute(cat /tmpfile | tr -d '\n' |base64 -d > dest)
```

It really only depends on `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SCP2 is one way, from your local machine to the remote.  I was able to go the other way rather easily though.

- I archived the folder on the remote I wanted to pull with

  ```
  tar cvf folder folder.tar
  ```

  then did

  ```
  base64 folder.tar
  ```
- Copy the text output and paste it into a file on your local machine, `folder.tar.txt`.
- Decode with

  ```
  base64 -d folder.tar.txt > folder.tar
  ```

  and then extract the tar with

  ```
  tar xvf folder.tar
  ```